# Images not loading using Picasso no error given

Tags: android, picasso

The images only show when using the stock android emulator but not in geny motion or an actual android device running 4+ and Picasso 2.3.4.

This is the code I'm using:

```
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(EventViewActivity.this).listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("ERROR?", exception.getMessage());
    }
}).build();

picasso.with(EventViewActivity.this).setLoggingEnabled(true);
picasso.with(EventViewActivity.this).setIndicatorsEnabled(true);

picasso.with(EventViewActivity.this).load(selEvent.photoThumbURLs.get(x)).into(iv, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {}

        @Override
        public void onError() {
            Log.i("INFO","WHAT IS THE ERROR?!!");
        }
    });
}
```

This is all I get as an error onImageLoadFailed never runs for me

```
09-20 10:05:01.836  14329-14329/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Main        created      [R2] Request{http://www.[[SITE]].com/BBT/uploads/322f6253-e018-40d9-9c02-ad8ac15a9e66/thumb_photo-0-vLTRb.jpg}
09-20 10:05:01.836  14329-14619/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Dispatcher  enqueued     [R2]+4ms
09-20 10:05:01.866  14329-14621/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Hunter      executing    [R2]+30ms
09-20 10:05:02.016  14329-14329/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Main        errored      [R1]+1791ms
09-20 10:05:02.016  14329-14619/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Dispatcher  delivered    [R1]+1793ms
09-20 10:05:02.387  14329-14619/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Dispatcher  retrying     [R2]+548ms
09-20 10:05:02.387  14329-14622/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Hunter      executing    [R2]+554ms
09-20 10:05:02.917  14329-14619/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Dispatcher  retrying     [R2]+1077ms
09-20 10:05:02.917  14329-14633/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Hunter      executing    [R2]+1078ms
09-20 10:05:03.428  14329-14619/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Dispatcher  batched      [R2]+1590ms for error (will replay)
09-20 10:05:03.628  14329-14329/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis I/INFO? WHAT IS THE ERROR?!!
09-20 10:05:03.628  14329-14329/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Main        errored      [R2]+1794ms
09-20 10:05:03.638  14329-14619/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Dispatcher  delivered    [R2]+1805ms
09-20 10:11:48.703  14329-14619/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Dispatcher  replaying    [R2]+406s
09-20 10:11:48.713  14329-14637/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Hunter      executing    [R2]+406s
09-20 10:11:48.753  14329-14619/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Dispatcher  enqueued     [R2]+406s
09-20 10:11:48.763  14329-14619/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Dispatcher  replaying    [R1]+408s
09-20 10:11:48.763  14329-14619/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Hunter      joined       [R1]+408s to [R2]+406s, [R1]+408s
09-20 10:11:49.264  14329-14619/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Dispatcher  retrying     [R2]+407s, [R1]+409s
09-20 10:11:49.274  14329-14621/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Hunter      executing    [R2]+407s, [R1]+409s
09-20 10:11:49.794  14329-14619/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Dispatcher  retrying     [R2]+407s, [R1]+409s
09-20 10:11:49.794  14329-14622/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Hunter      executing    [R2]+407s, [R1]+409s
09-20 10:11:50.305  14329-14619/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Dispatcher  batched      [R2]+408s, [R1]+410s for error (will replay)
09-20 10:11:50.425  14329-14619/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Dispatcher  replaying    [R2]+408s
09-20 10:11:50.425  14329-14633/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Hunter      executing    [R2]+408s
09-20 10:11:50.435  14329-14619/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Dispatcher  enqueued     [R2]+408s
09-20 10:11:50.435  14329-14619/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Dispatcher  replaying    [R1]+410s
09-20 10:11:50.435  14329-14619/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Hunter      joined       [R1]+410s to [R2]+408s, [R1]+410s
09-20 10:11:50.515  14329-14329/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis I/INFO? WHAT IS THE ERROR?!!
09-20 10:11:50.515  14329-14329/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Main        errored      [R2]+408s
09-20 10:11:50.515  14329-14329/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Main        errored      [R1]+410s
09-20 10:11:50.515  14329-14619/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Dispatcher  delivered    [R2]+408s, [R1]+410s
09-20 10:11:50.945  14329-14619/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Dispatcher  retrying     [R2]+409s, [R1]+410s
09-20 10:11:50.945  14329-14637/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Hunter      executing    [R2]+409s, [R1]+410s
09-20 10:11:51.456  14329-14619/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Dispatcher  retrying     [R2]+409s, [R1]+411s
09-20 10:11:51.456  14329-14621/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Hunter      executing    [R2]+409s, [R1]+411s
09-20 10:11:51.956  14329-14619/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Dispatcher  batched      [R2]+410s, [R1]+411s for error (will replay)
09-20 10:11:52.166  14329-14329/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis I/INFO? WHAT IS THE ERROR?!!
09-20 10:11:52.166  14329-14329/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Main        errored      [R2]+410s
09-20 10:11:52.166  14329-14619/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Dispatcher  delivered    [R2]+410s, [R1]+411s
09-20 10:11:52.166  14329-14329/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Main        errored      [R1]+411s
09-20 10:12:54.577  14329-14619/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Dispatcher  replaying    [R2]+472s
09-20 10:12:54.577  14329-14622/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Hunter      executing    [R2]+472s
09-20 10:12:54.597  14329-14619/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Dispatcher  enqueued     [R2]+472s
09-20 10:12:54.607  14329-14619/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Dispatcher  replaying    [R1]+474s
09-20 10:12:54.637  14329-14619/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Hunter      joined       [R1]+474s to [R2]+472s, [R1]+474s
09-20 10:12:55.158  14329-14619/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Dispatcher  retrying     [R2]+473s, [R1]+474s
09-20 10:12:55.158  14329-14633/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Hunter      executing    [R2]+473s, [R1]+474s
09-20 10:12:55.718  14329-14619/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Dispatcher  retrying     [R2]+473s, [R1]+475s
09-20 10:12:55.718  14329-14637/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Hunter      executing    [R2]+473s, [R1]+475s
09-20 10:12:56.229  14329-14619/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Dispatcher  batched      [R2]+474s, [R1]+476s for error (will replay)
09-20 10:12:56.429  14329-14329/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis I/INFO? WHAT IS THE ERROR?!!
09-20 10:12:56.429  14329-14329/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Main        errored      [R2]+474s
09-20 10:12:56.439  14329-14329/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Main        errored      [R1]+476s
09-20 10:12:56.439  14329-14619/com.cavedgeeks.barbadostennis D/Picasso? Dispatcher  delivered    [R2]+474s, [R1]+476s
```

EDIT: Seems like the issue is directly related to my site, imgur and other sites work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like I had to uninstall the app then run it again on the device for it to work for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use picasso only. Then it can't be your solution.

In Picasso, u don't have option to find the exception. 
It provides only

```
@Override public void onSuccess() {
}
@Override public void onError() {
}
```

Try this [Glide library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki) and it is similar to Picasso like one line code

```
    public boolean onException(Exception e, T model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, T model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks I'll be sure to check out the Glide library as an alternative.

Comment: This is not true. You have `com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.Listener#onImageLoadFailed(Picasso, Uri, Exception)` since Picasso 1.1.0, and you can use it by `Picasso.Builder#listener(Listener)`.